# What to do with completely bold answers?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed series of answers that are completely bolded. I agree that bolding is good for emphasizing main points of a post, however, **if everything is emphasized, nothing is actually emphasized.**

Moreover, my personal opinion is that, such answers stand out so much that they are unpleasant to look at.

Therefore, I suggest that those should be edited on-sight and normalized.

Answer (score 3):

If you see a poorly formatted post, you can edit it.  That's what the edit feature is for.  As they say on Wikipedia, [be bold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBOLD) *(in this case, be bold by unbolding)*

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you, and they can be edited as you mentioned. JazakAllah-Khaira mate.

Answer (score 2):

Such answers are mostly provided by new users (observed). They should be edited out and the emphasis removed and only the part that matters be emphasized. They stand out with a negative impression (imposing and dogmatic) rather then positive.

Similar discussion was previously brought up in *[Big mass of ill formatted and put posts](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/846/3487)*.

---

I personally don't even like to read them (unpleasant).

It's more psychological. When the answer's content doesn't completely or partially satisfy the question it's made bold to make-up for it and give a hollow impression of a good answer. Not the only reason though.